# C# in Page_Load puts code on top of <html>

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

More specifically, I have made a small webpage using `C#` and a `.aspx` document. All `C#` code I have put in the `<head>` part of my document, inside `Page_Load` like this:

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(Object s, EventArgs e) {  
     Response.Write(@"<div class=""header"">Foo Bar</div>");
     ...
}
</script>
```

This works somehow, but the problem is that the html generated by this gets stuffed on top of the beginning `<html>` tag in the document which results in a broken character setting (doesn't read the meta tag?) and strange things not supposed to happen. I'm new to using `ASP.NET` and it's obvious. Where would I put all my statements so that they would be reachable from the `<body>` using `<%` delimiters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would put them in the body. This particular code doesn't do anything more than write directly to the spot where you've put it.

```
<body>

    <%= @"<div class=""header"">Foo Bar</div>"; %>

</body>
```

I'm sure this is just a test of something, but if you want to write to a specific place in the page you'd be better off using a label or literal control:

```
<head>
<script language="#C" runat="server">

    <script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(Object s, EventArgs e)
    {  
         this.lblWriteToMe.Text = @"<div class=""header"">Foo Bar</div>");
         // ...
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <asp:Label ID="lblWriteToMe" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**
In order to place text in an html block you would put that directly into the html block you want it to appear in as I did in the first sample. It's a very "classic asp" method of doing it, though MVC is bringing the concept back. The script tag at the top can hold all of the method/event definitions and global variables/properties or whatever, but when you use `Response.Write` or `<%=` it will output it as soon as it appears. Keep in mind, that a standard webforms page has an event lifecycle that has to be considered and `Response.Write` can interfere with that. If you have output generated in methods or events, you would be better off posting that result into a control. This will allow the control to determine the proper order of rendering within the html block as it comes out in `Page_Render`.

Comment: Ok. What if I have an array `arr` defined somewhere in a `<script>` and I want to reference that array from a `<%` context (ie. `foreach (String s in arr) { Response.Write(s); }`)?

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand a little bit more now. Ended up replacing every `Response.Write` statement with a `myString +=` statement and then doing a `this.code.Text = myString` and referencing that in the body with `<asp:Label id="code" ..`.